# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API - custom json

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

In my project, I have a table called `product (Id, name)` it has 10K plus rows. I would return JSON object in the below format.

I have a `Product` class in C# `(Id, name)`. When I do Http get it return `[{id: "", name:""},{id: "", name:""}]`. I would like to warp return array of `"Product" :[]`

Current return is

```
[
    {
        "id": "3089e0d5-476f-407a-9458-949d0d08123f"
         "name": "Laptop"
     },
     {
        "id": "3089e0d5-476f-407a-9458-949d0d08123f"
         "name": "Mobile"
     }
  ]
```

Desired result is:

```
  "product":
    [
    {
        "id": "3089e0d5-476f-407a-9458-949d0d08123f"
         "name": "Laptop"
     },
     {
        "id": "3089e0d5-476f-407a-9458-949d0d08123f"
         "name": "Mobile"
     }
  ]
```

Please advice

Comment: I am using below code but it's not wrapping as "products": [{},{}]. It only return [{},{}]

public async Task<IActionResult> GetProduct()
        {
            var proRepo = await _productRepository.GetProducts();
            return Ok(_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Models.ProductDto>>(proRepo ));
        }

public class ProductDto
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
      
    }

Comment: I have updated my answer,you can refer to it.

Comment: Hello,is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.you can try to use the following code directly:

```
return Ok(new { products = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Models.ProductDto>>(proRepo) });
```

2.Another way,you can try to create

```
 public class ViewModel
    {
        public List<Product> product { get; set; }
      
    }
```

and then use

```
return Ok(new ViewModel{ products = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Models.ProductDto>>(proRepo) });
```